# Need Definition for closing questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Need Definition for Closing questions

1. What is not programming related ? What is bountry for this ?
2. What is not a real question ? how the questions are considered not a real question

IN STACK OVERFLOW SITE ...

Comment: Because people are not thinking about anything just start closing question with out any guideline.. So i just want to know rule for that.. other wise every one  follow own rule ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not Programming Related - Your question either has nothing to do with programming or can be seen as so general (work environment, careers, society) that the programming related part of it is minimal or non-existent.
- Not A Real Question - This can typically refer to questions that are not questions. If you make a question and all you are doing is ranting or rambling about a topic, or your question is so mangled that it is undecipherable, Not A Real Question will generally be the close reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can read the [close reasons definitions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/describing-close-reasons). They also show up as tooltips when closing. You can start to vote to close at +3000 reputation, as the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) will tell you.

Tooltip on voting to close for

**Not programming related**: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way. This question is very far afield from programming.

Comment: Voting to close starts at 3,000 Rep.

Comment: where is definition for not programming related

Comment: Link in answer now gives a 404.